# Is it possible to run Watir test in parallel?

Tags: watir

I have simple [Watir](http://watir.com/) tests.
Each test is self-contained, no shared state or dependency of any kind. Each test open and close the browser.

Is it possible to run the test in parallel to reduce the time to run all tests?
Even only 2 or 3 tests in parallel can reduce the time dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests#setup-for-non-rails) Ruby gem. Depending on your setup, running the tests in parallel could be as simple as this:

```
parallel_cucumber features/
```